# Idiom/saying for "there was no possible better solution at the time"

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Context: "We did the best we could. There wasn't much else we could have done because *there was no possible better solution at the time*"

The problem I have with what's already written is that it sounds a little too wordy.

Comment: 'This was the best that could be done at the time.'

Comment: It's the best we know how.

Comment: *"We were **out of options**"*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***[Make do](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/make-do)*** comes to mind:

> - Manage with the limited or inadequate means available. (ODO)

- We had to make do with the solutions we could offer at that time.

Comment: I knew it was something along those lines, thanks. I'll accept your answer tomorrow

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, you just gotta [play the hand you're dealt](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/play+the+hand+you're+dealt)

> To accept, deal with, and make the most of one's current situation or
>   circumstances; to make use of that which one is afforded or has
>   available. I know you feel unsatisfied with your life at the moment,
>   but we all have to play the hand we're dealt. Just keep working hard
>   and things are bound to improve! I never asked to be responsible for
>   the business, but I'm going to play the hand I was dealt.

play the hand you're dealt. (n.d.) Farlex Dictionary of Idioms. (2015). Retrieved July 18 2016 from http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/play+the+hand+you%27re+dealt